# iPhone Full and Lite version without StoreKit

Tags: iphone

I have a Full and Lite applications that were built from the same code. Lite version has a button Upgrade. What code I should place in button's handler for checking users payment and update application to Full version??
I know StoreKit framework that allow to unblock some features, but I need just 2 different applications.

Maybe there is tutorial on this topic, but I found nothing.
If anyone has reference link pls provide

None of those applications has not yet uploaded to Appstore.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want two versions of the app Full and Lite. Not sure why you would want to go down that route if you're planning on implementing the StoreKit in the Lite version.

It makes it alot easier to maintain and develop 1 version of the app instead of 2 versions of the app.

Look at it from this stand-point. If/when you makes changes to the Full version you're going to have to make those same changes in the Lite version. That's double the amount of code to write/copy-paste.

Take a look at this tutorial that explains and shows how-to implement StoreKit in your app.

[iPhone Tutorial – In-App Purchases](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-%E2%80%93-in-app-purchases/)

I would recommend that you develop, and maintain only 1 version of the app. That would be the Lite version with the option to un-lock all the features that the Full version would have.

A couple benefits to this approach is:

- Ease of application development and future enhancements
- Higher rate of conversion from Lite to Full version

Hope this info helps

Answer (score 4):

You can't buy other applications from an applications.

When your upgrade button is activated, you can only open link to the full version using App Store. When opening App Store, your application will be closed and the phone will handle the rest. Then it is up to the user if she chooses to purchase your application. The lite version will stay installed even after the purchase until the user uninstalls it.

See [Technical Q&A QA1629](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2008/qa1629.html) for details how to implement the linking.